# Plotting line with marker as head

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code that produces an animation of drawing a circle.

```
from math import cos, sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_plot(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    line.axes.axis([-1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5])
    return line

def plot_circle():
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(100):
        x.append(cos(i/10.0))
        y.append(sin(i/10.0))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    line, = ax.plot(x, y, color = "k")
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line], interval = 1, blit = False)
    plt.show()

plot_circle()
```

The line is longer than a full lap, and so to be able to still see the drawing when the line overlaps, I would like a marker that shows what is being drawn. I tried to add a scatter plot  into the update call, like

```
scat = plt.scatter(0, 0)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line, scat], interval = 1, blit = False)
```

and try to update the position of the scatter-plot point using `x[num]` and `y[num]` in `update_plot` without success. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to add the scatter plot to the same animation. The key was to use `scat.set_offsets` to set the data. The changes that are needed is as follows:

```
def update_plot(num, x, y, line, scat):
    # ...
    scat.set_offsets([x[num - 1], y[num - 1]])
    return line, scat

def plot_circle():
    # ...
    scat = ax.scatter([0], [0], color = 'k') # Set the dot at some arbitrary position initially
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line, scat], interval = 1, blit = False)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `scat` in `update_plot()`.

Here is another method, draw the line with `markevery` argument:

```
line, = ax.plot(x, y, "-o", color="k", markevery=100000)
```

reverse the points order:

```
line.set_data(x[:num][::-1], y[:num][::-1])
```

for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

t = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)

pl.plot(x[::-1], y[::-1], "-o", markevery=10000)
```

outputs:

[image]

Comment: Really interesting solution!